# Microsoft Excel - Rolling Average with Skips

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have a table of costs among several different locations for the past x years.  For each location (A, B, C), I would like to find the average cost of the past three visits.  Unfortunately, locations are often skipped.  What's the best way I can make an excel formula that will correctly calculate this average?  Below is an example table of the calculation.

Thank you!

| Year | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | N/A | 20 |
| 2020 | N/A | 15 | 20 |
| 2019 | 20 | N/A | 20 |
| 2018 | 30 | N/A | 1000 |
| 2017 | N/A | 45 | 1000 |
| 2016 | 1000 | 75 | 1000 |
| **Most recent 3-time avg** | **20** | **45** | **20** |

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

The example below is should probably help, but it is based on ordering to have the newest last.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is located in A1:D7. In B8 :

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(COUNTIF(B2:B4,"N/A")=0,B2:B4,IF(COUNTIF(B2:B5,"N/A")=1,B2:B5,IF(COUNTIF(B2:B6,"N/A")=2,B2:B6,IF(COUNTIF(B2:B7,"N/A")=3,B2:B7,ERROR.TYPE(1)))))),"notEnufData")
```

& drag rightwards.

Idea : the range for `average()` will change depending on the number of "N/A" in the encountered range. if "N/A" is > 3, return error msg.

Please share if it works/understandable/not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B$1:B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(B$2:B$7)*ROW(B$2:B$7),{1;2;3})))
```

- Formula will return an error if there are fewer than three values.

  - *you can use `IFERROR` to return a meaningful message, if you want*
- Assumes most recent visit on top

[image]